# coin toss and probability or prime number of tosses

Tags: probability, number-theory

Toss a fair coin until the last coin toss is different than the previous ones.

Examples :

H, H, H, **T**

T, T, **H**

H, **T**

etc.

What is the probability that the number of tosses, minus 1, is a prime ?

For example : T, T, **H** we have 2 tails, and 2 is prime.
But H, H, H, H, **T** 4 heads; 4 is not prime.

Without loss of generality lets say first toss is head (H).

Then the sum of the probabilities :

$$S = P(H, H, T) + P (H, H, H, T) + P(H, H, H, H, H, T) + ... $$

$$S = \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{2^5} + \frac{1}{2^7}... $$

seems to be equal to the infinite sum of the inverses of 2 to the power of the primes.

Obviously this probability is well defined, but what's the value ?

(Approximation for the first thousand primes gives : 0.414682509851)

It's probably irrational, but is it also transcendental ?

Comment: It is irrational because it is not periodic in binary.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_constant includes a proof of the irrationality. It is not mentioned whether the number is transcendental, but numerical analysis indicates that it is.